# Google Maps JS API v3: prioritize event listeners

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wonder if there is a subtle way to somehow prioritize event listeners, i.e. change the order they're being called, ***without* changing the order they're added**. Snippet:

```
var listener1 = function () {
        console.log('@listener1');
    },
    listener2 = function () {
        console.log('@listener2');
    };

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', listener1);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', listener2);

/*
 * Prioritize the listeners here: I would like to have `listener2` 
 * called before `listener1`.
 */
//
//
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/glenn/2hfLnquq/).

Answer (score 1):

Have a single event listener defined, with a wrapper function that calls the two functions in the way you want, e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    listener2();
    listener1();
});
```

Alternatively, I suspect there's something more complicated going on that you're not letting us know about in your question.  In which case you could add each function into an array, perhaps keyed with priority.  Then loop through the array in your event listener.

```
var listeners = [];

var listener1 = function () {
    console.log('@listener1');
},
listener2 = function () {
    console.log('@listener2');
};

listeners.push(listener2);
listeners.push(listener1);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
        listeners[i]();
    }
});
```